# Cleaning of ImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I need to clean ImageView. I have some figures there.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

I tried using

```
imageView.image = nil
```

but it doesn't work. How can I clean imageView?

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work? Is the image still there?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, still there.

Comment: If you plan to show other images in the view, just hide the imageView (`isHidden = true`), else just use Sweeper's suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure `imageView` refers to the correct image view? Try setting some other properties like `frame` and see if you can see the changes.

Comment: how about tweaking the `hidden` or `alpha` property inherited from `UIView`

Comment: @Sweeper I get "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

Comment: @Vladislav Then your outlet isn't connected. You need to connect the outlet from the storyboard.

Comment: @Sweeper I connected the outlet with storyboard. I can use different properties, but when I use 'imageView.image = nil', nothing happens.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is maddeningly un-helpful. Please edit your question to state your goal, and how the code you posted fails to meet that goal. For example: "I have an image view that displays an image. I would like to be able to remove the image from the view and have it show the background color instead. My current code is `imageView.image=nil`. That code runs without crashing, but once it's been executed "the image is still visible.

Comment: @DuncanC How can I make an image dissapear and leave only background color visible?

Comment: I just made that up. Edit your question to state your actual goal.

Comment: If you want the view controller's background color to show through then you should set the image view's hidden property to true. Then the image view will disappear and whatever is behind it will become visible.

Comment: @DuncanC When I use imageView.isHidden = true, I have black screen.

Comment: What is behind the image view? Try setting the background color on the view controller's content view to a known color.

Answer (score 1):

ARC counts the *strong* references to an object. If there is none, that object is deallocated.

If your the image view isn't strongly referenced from anywhere else, then removing it from the view hierarchy should do the job:

```
imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: The code in the question is not setting a weak property to `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, misread the question.

Comment: @rmaddy is right. Furthermore, I believe that the OP just wants to 'clear' the image from the imageview, not release the object.

Comment: @Sweeper you're right. I just want to clear the screen.

Comment: Your code should work. What exactly "does not" work?